# Complex mongodb query with arrays operations

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have got a collection of documents like:

```json
{
    _id: ObjectId("63f4c47a6edd646542c4a2c9"),
    title: 'ABCDEF',
    counter: 230,
    values: [
      {
        a: 4,
        b: 4,
        date: ISODate("2023-02-21T00:00:00.000Z")
      },
      {
        a: 2,
        b: 4,
        date: ISODate("2023-02-25T00:00:00.000Z")
      }
    ]
}
```

I would like to find all documents which have `counter` less than 201 and which `value` with the highest `date` has `'b'` greater than `'a'` by some minimum ratio: let's say 2.

How to accomplish that?

BR

Comment: would you like to describe what is `a` and `b`? because if you are asking for `ratio`, it should comparing result with  `devider`| `a/b ` in each element of the array. and if we only  to find the highest `date`, you dont need `ratio` there. because its useless.

Comment: Let me put it in other words: I would like to list only these documents which value with the greatest date has 'b' greater than 'a' at least 2 times. So the following pairs of a and b included:  (1, 2), (1, 3), (5, 10), (5, 100), ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can try this query:

- First get only documents with `counter` less than 201.
- Then create an aux field with the highest date element from the array. Sorting array by date and getting the first will give desired one.
- Then `$match` again to filter elements where the ratio between `a` and `b` is greater than 2 (i.e. `b > a * 2`.).
- And last step is `$project` to not output the aux value and only show the document itself.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "counter": { "$lt": 201 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "auxvalue": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$sortArray": {
              "input": "$values",
              "sortBy": { "date": -1 }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gte": [
          "$auxvalue.b",
          {
            "$multiply": [ "$auxvalue.a", 2 ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": { "auxvalue": 0 }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vKA2YcwJu8G)

Comment: _"... 'b' greater than 'a' by some minimum ratio: let's say 2"_ I'm not sure what is meant by that either.  In case it's actually a _ratio_, here's a nearly identical [mongoplayground.net example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pNpavQ6pw3S "Click me!") that checks the _ratio_.

Comment: Let me put it in other words: I would like to list only these documents which value with the greatest date has 'b' greater than 'a' at least 2 times. So the following pairs of a and b included:  (1, 2), (1, 3), (5, 10), (5, 100), ...

Comment: So is [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vKA2YcwJu8G) what are you looking for?

Comment: Yeah, sort of :) thanks!